# Programmatically Render a Webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm attempting to render a webform inside a block plugin. I'm able to successfully retrieve the webform using the following code

```
$webform = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load('my_webform');
```

However I'd like to render this form. I've attempted using

```
return $webform;
```

But I receive the error

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Element::isEmpty() must be of the type array,
>   object given

I'm assuming this is because $webform isn't formatted as a proper render array, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've been searching for clues inside the code of the original webform module, but I haven't been able to find anything.

How would I programmatically render a webform? And/or is there a way to find in the code of a module or entity the way to render that entity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to find a method for the webform entity class called getSubmissionForm. I found it in the webform module code in src/Entity/Webform.php

I invoked it like so

```
$webform = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load('my_webform');
$webform = $webform->getSubmissionForm();

return $webform;
```

Which returned the specified webform rendered.

Comment: @see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-embed-a-webform

Answer (score 12):

You can also just return a render array.

```
[
  '#type' => 'webform',
  '#webform' => 'my_webform',
  '#default_data' => [
    'nid' => 10
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 8):

Matt answers works for me but if you want to have a more complete theme structure with it, you would better use :

```
$webform      = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load('my_webform');
$view_builder = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getViewBuilder('webform');
$build        = $view_builder->view($webform);
return $build;
```

> To render this webform as a render array and to add it to your output

Answer (score 2):

To render a Webform inside a Block plugin, you can use [Block Token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_token) for that. It will allow you to create the tokens for your blocks.

To create a webform block, go to *Block Layout*, then *Place* a block, then check the *Create the token for this block* checkbox for the block. Now the specific webform should be available as a block.

Here is the example to manually render the above created webform block:

```
$block = BlockViewBuilder::lazyBuilder('mywebform', 'full', 1);
$block_content = render($block);
```