# How to insert form into existing page template

Tags: 8, theming

Working in D8, I am trying to insert a form into an already created page/template file.

I am using webforms, and on the webform submission page (that lists the submission details), I am trying to insert a custom form to do some additional stuff. I already have the form generated, but I cannot find the correct way to insert the form into the template/page.

I tried using `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(form_name)` in the twig template where I wanted it, but Drupal didn't like that.

I then tried to use `hook_page_bottom` and `hook_page_top`, but that quite literally attaches it to the very top of the page, or very bottom of the page (outside of the bounds of the theme/template), not where I want it to be.

I am already overriding the template using the naming convention **webform-submission--webform-machine-name.html.twig**.

I am assuming since you can override the default templates for webform submissions, that the webform module implements `hook_theme` or some other similar hook. Is there a way I can hook into this hook and pass the form off as a variable, then just render it in the actual template using `{{ form }}`, or do I need to create my own override and pass both the submission data and the form data into it?

I miss the days when I could just use `$form = drupal_get_form();` and print `render($form);` inside of the template exactly where I wanted it.

Comment: Thank you for the  cleanup.

Comment: There is a webform reference field for content types, and you can also add this field to a custom block type. Is there a reason this may not be a good approach for you? Is your custom form not a webform?

Comment: Correct. It's a module created form that is generated programmatically. I could make the form a block on the page, but then I'm not able to stick it specifically where I want it on the page and it'll place it either above or below the content on the page. There's a specific place in the content it needs to live.

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231200/programmatically-render-a-webform

Comment: This isn't a related question. I'm not trying to render a webform in a page, I'm trying to render a programmatically built form inside of a different programmatically built page. I can't render the form directly in the twig template so I'm looking for another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this myself using `template_preprocess()` and generating the form from there